# VB.Net: Why is XmlDocument.Load Causing Problems?

Tags: xml, vb.net

So first, here's a bit of my code... it's almost identical to many snippets I've found on the internet.

```
1: Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
2: doc.Load("text.xml")
3: Dim docElement As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
```

So, here's my problem:

I can put anything before line 2, and it works fine. However, anything that I put after line 2 is completely ignored - it's as if doc.Load is causing the program to skip straight to the end of the sub. I've tried adding breakpoints at each line, the ones before and up to 2 are run, and then 3 and later are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As seems to be the pattern with me... I have found the answer to my question right after actually deciding I need to ask it.

If anyone else is having similar troubles: check for typos in the file name and/or check that the file exists. I feel dumb now.

Comment: so what was the problem then? typos or file does not exist?

Comment: Well...both... as far as the Load method is concerned, it was that the file didn't exist. In this case, it was caused by me typing the file name incorrectly. In other cases, maybe the file was deleted, or never created in the first place, or is in the wrong folder. Doesn't matter the cause - it's the same thing. The file is not where the computer is searching.